# In R, the output of my linear model shows a positive correlation but my ggplot graph indicates a negative correlation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I'm trying to identify the impact of how Sycamore_biomass affects the day which a bird lays its first_egg. My model output indicates a weak positive relationship - i.e. as sycamore biomass increases, the day of the first egg being laid should increase (i.e. should be later) (note I'm including confounding factors in this model):

```
Call:
lm(formula = First_egg ~ Sycamore_biomass + Distance_to_road + 
    Distance_to_light + Anthropogenic_cover + Canopy_cover, data = egglay_date)

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)         39.61055   16.21391   2.443   0.0347 *
Sycamore_biomass     0.15123    0.53977   0.280   0.7851  
Distance_to_road     0.01773    0.46323   0.038   0.9702  
Distance_to_light   -0.02626    0.44225  -0.059   0.9538  
Anthropogenic_cover -0.13879    0.28306  -0.490   0.6345  
Canopy_cover        -0.30219    0.20057  -1.507   0.1628  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12.99 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2363,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1455 
F-statistic: 0.6189 on 5 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.6891
```

However, when I plot this using ggplot, the regression line indicates a negative relationship? Can anyone help me out with what is happening here?

```
ggplot(egglay_date, aes(x=Sycamore_biomass, y=First_egg)) +
  geom_point(shape=19, alpha=1/4) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

[GG PLOT of Sycamore biomass and First egg date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f14vO.png)

Comment: What happens if you run the linear model without the confounding variables? i.e., lm(First_egg ~ Sycamore_biomass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is because you look at the raw data you fed into the model, not the model predictions. In the plot, you don't "isolate" a single predictor. You look at the result of all predictors doing something to the response variable. I suppose the effect of this predictor is "overshadowed" by the effects of the other predictors.

To take a look at the effect of solely one predictor, you need to predict new values from the model while fixing all other predictors. You can try something along the lines of:

```
  preds <- predict(yourmodel, newdata = data.frame(
    "Sycamore_biomass" = 0:25,
    "Distance_to_road" = mean(egglay_date$Distance_to_road),
    "Distance_to_light" = mean(egglay_date$Distance_to_light),
    "Anthropogenic_cover" = mean(egglay_date$Anthropogenic_cover),
    "Canopy_cover" = mean(egglay_date$Canopy_cover)))
  
  new_data <- data.frame(
    "Sycamore_biomass" = 0:25,
    "First_egg" = preds)
  
  ggplot(new_data, aes(x=Sycamore_biomass, y=First_egg)) +
    geom_point(shape=19, alpha=1/4) +
    geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

This should give you the predictions of your model when only considering the effect of the one predictor.

Comment: Hi Zoe, ok thank you. So I think I'm a bit confused about what ggplot is plotting. That line it creates, is that just raw data as opposed to predictions? I am a bit confused as I've plotted the same data using two other methods - and I have specifically included predict functions for both - and the end result is the exact same. As a note, I have a quite small sample size (circa 17), might that be impacting it? Thanks

Comment: Exactly, ggplot does not know you fitted a model, it only gets the raw data that you provide. It creates a regression just for your x and y and ignores all other variables in the data frame. And then it shows you the line it fitted for exactly these two variables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is quite simple (but I understand why it may seems complex at first).

First off, your model indicates a positive relationship because you have included all your other variables.  Keep in mind, your best fit line through your data here is when you take **all** your data points, and fit a line to make the sum of residuals = 0.  Note: this is not the same as sum of residuals squared.

Since you didn't provide your data (please do on future posts, or at least, something to work with), I will illustrate my point with the `data(mtcars)` built into R

```
data("mtcars")

df <- mtcars
```

This dataset has many variables, to see them all, just type `names(df)`

Lets just work with three of them to see if miles per gallon (mpg) is explained by:

```
   1) cyl : # of cylinders
   2) hp : horse power
   3) drat : rear axle ratio
```

```
attach(df)
model <-lm(mpg~cyl+hp+drat)
summary(model)
```

Let's say, I just want to plot the relationship between cylinders and mpg (for you, it would be sycamour biomass and bird lay). Here, from our model summary, we see that our relationship is negative (negative estimate, aka, coefficient), and that the intercept is at 22.5.
[image]

So I do what you just did and just plot mpg~cly (without considering my other variables)

```
plot(mpg~cyl, pch=15, col="blue",cex=2, cex.axis=2, ylab="MPG", xlab="Number of Cylinders", cex.lab=1.5)
abline(lm(mpg~cyl),lwd=2,col="red")
```

[image]

First off, we see that the y intercept is not 22.5, but rather above 25.

If I were to do the math from first model, if I had 4 cylinders, I should predict:

22.51406 + (4 * -1.3606) =  17.07

So lets see if our prediction is correct on our graph

[image]

Definitely not.

So lets run a new model (which you need to do), where we model **just mpg~cly**

```
reduced_model <- lm(mpg~cyl)

summary(reduced_model)
```

[image]

See how the intercept and coefficent (estimates) changed?  Yours will too when you run a reduced model.  Lets see if the plots now make sense following the same steps as above with predicting 4 cylinders

```
37.8846  + (4 * -2.8758 ) # 26.38
plot(mpg~cyl, pch=15, col="blue",cex=2, cex.axis=2, ylab="MPG", xlab="Number of Cylinders", cex.lab=1.5)
abline(lm(mpg~cyl),lwd=2,col="red")
abline(h=26.38,v=4,lwd=2, col="green")
```

[image]

Looks like everything checks out.

Summary: You need to run a simple model with just your two variables of interest if you want to correctly understand your plot

Comment: Ok awesome that does make sense, thank you so much. Will reduce my model so it only contains the single predictor

Comment: Hi Andy, I have tried but i don't have enough 'reputation' to do so at this time. Apologies